# Need an elegant way to overload a command in a Bash script dynamically created and called by another tool

Tags: linux, bash, alias

There have been a lot of posts about how to overload commands in Bash, either by creating an alias or function, or just changing the script itself or how it is called; these methods make perfect sense to me but don't apply to the problem I'm trying to solve.

It is common in the semiconductor industry to work with EDA tools that provide API commands inside a Tcl interpreter; in my case the EDA tool generates a Bash script, then executes it one API call, so I only have access to the script after the script executed and cannot modify how it is called since that happens under the hood; there is also no blessed method for modifying the commands of interest that are written into the script.

What complicates this further is that this script is generated and called by the EDA tool inside a Singularity container; also, the command that is being called resides in a different EDA tool container, so this command 'vsim' must be transformed into an ssh call to our workload manager (slurm).  Example:
`vsim <args>`
Must be converted to:
`ssh <some-host> <ssh-options> "srun <srun-options> vsim <args>"`

Again, setting an alias or function called 'vsim' in the parent shell didn't work for me; the alias/function was not inherited by the subprocess (this is difficult for me to accept).  I also tried creating a symlink called 'vlog' that pointed at a static dispatcher script; this worked by I'd rather not hard code the path to the dispatcher as a file path; I would rather use a variable, like `vlog -> .../<resource>/$VERSION/bin/dispatch_for_flows`, but symlinks are not dynamic.

I'm thinking that I should still use the symlink approach but instead of pointing at the dispatcher, I'd point at a wrapper that does a single line exec of an interpolated path to the dispatcher, but I'm still not believing that setting an alias didn't solve the problem.  For years I wrote Csh scripts with full paths to commands to get around user aliases; with Bash, it looks like aliases are not inherited ever, even with the shopt 'expanand_alias' on in the parent shell or even in /etc/profile.  What am I missing here?

Can someone get the example below to work?  I'd like the script to inherit the alias from the parent shell and execute without the "command not found" error, without modification to the script or how it is called.  Again, I have no access to the script before it is executed and can't control how it is called; bash is the parent shell, bash is the script, and I do have root access on the OS so I could change the version of bash if neccessary (using 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu))

```
$ alias hello='echo world'
$ hello
world
$ shopt | grep expand_aliases
expand_aliases  on
$ cat test.bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -x
alias
shopt | grep expand_aliases
shopt -s expand_aliases
shopt | grep expand_aliases
hello

$ ./test.bash
+ alias
+ shopt
+ grep expand_aliases
expand_aliases  off
+ shopt -s expand_aliases
+ shopt
+ grep expand_aliases
expand_aliases  on
+ hello
./test.bash: line 7: hello: command not found
```

Comment: I've decided to got with an approach of breaking out of the container by creating a directory of symlinks for programs that need to exist in the search path but don't.  The symlinks point at script that does an exec on the specific version of the dispatch script.  So call stack looks like:
`eda_script.bash` -> `vsim ...` (symlink in $PATH) -> `dispatch_wrapper ...` (one-liner that points to version specific dispatch tool) -> `.../<version>/dispatch --tool vsim -- ...` -> `ssh $HOST "srun vsim ..."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone get the example below to work?

No that's not possible with aliases - you can't export an alias. But you can export a function.

```
$ hello() { echo world; }
$ export -f hello
$ ./test.bash
world
```

You can create a custom command in `PATH`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "#!/bin/bash" "echo world" > /usr/local/bin/hello
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/hello
```

and similarly add a custom command and add new path with the command to PATH and export.

Comment: hello is a __bash__ function not a program, you can't `exec` to it. You can exec to bash which runs a function. `exec bash -c hello`.

Comment: Nice, I did not know that a function could be exported. FYI, I tried your function example; it worked in a script, but not when preceded by 'exec', ex. ``` $ cat test.bash #!/usr/bin/bash exec hello $ ./test.bash ./test.bash: line 2: exec: hello: not found ```

Comment: But my problem was to fake a program; the function thing is clever, but if I wanted to do an 'exec', then this approach wouldn't work.

Comment: Then create a file in PATH. Like the second solution.

Comment: In the end, the container itself needed to be broken out of, so to avoid the need to recompile, I augmented the PATH inside the container to include a breakout directory outside the container, where I would drop symlinks that point to a generic script that does ssh and a call to slurm.  Having functions or aliases in the build.def would not scale.  So I guess I did something like the 2nd answer.